# Python CGI Redirect not working

Tags: python, redirect, cgi, http-redirect

I don't have idea why this isn't working. This is the code (really the hole code):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print "Status: 301 Moved"
print "Location: http://www.python.org/"
print
```

Check out that the headers are printed ok, but the "Status" appears twice:

[image]

Any ideas?

I know there's a lot of questions like this one, but none of the answers can solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection) suggests that `Status: 301 Moved` is not sufficient to indicate the browser should proceed to a new location.  I believe you need to include `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`.  (Or use the `<meta http-equiv="Refresh"...` approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work. `print "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently";print "Location: http://www.python.org/";print`. I used to use the `<meta http-equiv="Refresh"...` approach but it's not the preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers.
Add the following line at the top:

**print 'Content-Type: text/html'**

I use this function to redirect:

```
def redirect(location)
    print "Content-Type: text/html"
    print "Status: 302 Found"
    print "Location: %s" % location
    print ""
```